# How to align user name on left side and points on right side with React bootstrap ListGroup?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a `map` which get all the users and their points.

My code looks like this:

```
return (
   <ListGroup>
     {data.map((user, index) => (
       <ListGroupItem key={index}>
         <b>
           {user.name} : {user.total_points}
         </b>
       </ListGroupItem>
     ))}
   </ListGroup>
);
```

Now its look like this:

[image: Leaderboard page]

How can I get the username on left side and the points on right side?
The points is showing as `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's Bootstrap, there's already a [float utility class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/) called `float-right`, by wrapping the `0` or `user.total_points` inside a `<span>` or similar element:

```
return (
   <ListGroup>
     {data.map((user, index) => (
       <ListGroupItem key={index}>
         <b>
           {user.name} : <span className="float-right">{user.total_points}</span>
         </b>
       </ListGroupItem>
     ))}
   </ListGroup>
);
```

Comment: Its not working :/ I wrapped {user.total_points} inside <span> but same result. But this one worked <span style={{ float: "right" }}>{user.total_points}</span> , Thanks for help!

Comment: Im using "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4"